# NSURL baseURL returns nil. Any other way to get the actual base URL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I think I don't understand the concept of "baseURL". This:

```
NSLog(@"BASE URL: %@ %@", [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.es"], [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.es"] baseURL]);
```

Prints this:

```
BASE URL: http://www.google.es (null)
```

And of course, in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I read this:

> Return Value
>   The base URL of the receiver. If the receiver is an absolute URL, returns nil.

I'd like to get from this example URL:

https://www.google.es/search?q=uiviewcontroller&aq=f&oq=uiviewcontroller&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

This base URL

https://www.google.es

My question is simple. Is there any cleaner way of getting the actual base URL without concatenating the scheme and the hostname? I mean, what's the purpose of base URL then?

Comment: What result, exactly, are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that:
I want from this URL for example: https://www.google.es/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cats to get the "base URL" part -> https://www.google.es

Answer (score 31):

`-baseURL` is a concept purely of `NSURL/CFURL` rather than URLs in general. If you did this:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"search?q=uiviewcontroller"
       relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.es/"]];
```

then `baseURL` would be `https://www.google.es/`. In short, `baseURL` is only populated if the `NSURL` is created using a method that explicitly passes in a base URL. The main purpose of this feature is to handle relative URL strings such as might be found in the source of a typical web page.

What you're after instead, is to take an arbitrary URL and strip it back to just the host portion. The easiest way I know to do this is a little cunning:

```
NSURL *aURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.es/search?q=uiviewcontroller"];
NSURL *hostURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"/" relativeToURL:aURL] absoluteURL];
```

This will give a `hostURL` of `https://www.google.es/`

I have such a method published as `-[NSURL ks_hostURL]` as part of [KSFileUtilities](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities) (scroll down the readme to find it documented)

If you want purely the host and not anything like scheme/port etc. then `-[NSURL host]` is your method.

Comment: Bottom line: "baseURL is only populated if the NSURL is created using a method that explicitly passes in a base URL". Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that in your example `hostURL` != `[NSURL URLWithString: https://www.google.es/]`. NSURL knows how they're constructed and doesn't consider them equivalent, even though their absolute URL are the same. I added a slightly modified version to my repo (sorry for the Swift):
`URL(string: "/", relativeTo: self).flatMap { URL(string: $0.absoluteString) }`

Answer (score 3):

Docs for BaseURL.

```
baseURL
Returns the base URL of the receiver.

- (NSURL *)baseURL
Return Value
The base URL of the receiver. If the receiver is an absolute URL, returns nil.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
NSURL.h
```

Seems it only works for relative URLs.

You could possibly use ...

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [url pathComponents]
```

and then take the bits you want.

Or try...

```
NSString *host = [url host];
```

Comment: The `pathComponents` will only decompose the `path`, so one can't take the baseURL from there (they can, but the strategy will be similar and more complex than using `path` simply). Also, `host` will omit the URL scheme (`http://` for example)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `host` method

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.hello.com"];

NSLog(@"Host:%@", url.host);
```

result:

```
Host:www.hello.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be just me, but when I think further about [the double-URL solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897956/3379766), it sounds like something that could stop working between OS updates. So I decided to share yet another solution, definitely not beautiful either, but I find it more readable by the general public since it doesn't rely on any hidden specificity of the framework.

```
if let path = URL(string: resourceURI)?.path {
  let baseURL = URL(string: resourceURI.replacingOccurrences(of: path, with: ""))
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by using `url.deletingLastPathComponent` method in Swift

```swift
let baseUrl = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result if there is more than one path component in the URL.

Comment: It is true that in my case I have only one path component. I had struggles to find answer to this  Other solutions did not work for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick, easy, and safe way to fetch the base URL:

```
NSError *regexError = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"http://.*/" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&regexError];

if (regexError) {
    NSLog(@"regexError: %@", regexError);
    return nil;
}

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:url.absoluteString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, url.absoluteString.length)];

NSString *baseURL = [url.absoluteString substringWithRange:match.range];
```

Comment: What about https and other schemes?