# How to get the url domain name with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, url, domain-name

When i get a url like`http://h5.m.abc.com/awp/base/cart.htm?#!/awp/base/cart.htm`,I just need the `abc.com`,what should I do?

EDIT: whatever how the url changes, I only need `abc.com`, for example:`http://h5.m.abc.com.cn/awp/base/cart.htm?#!/awp/base/cart.htm` I just need`abc.com.cn` 
`http://a.b.h.m.abc.cn/awp/base/cart.htm?#!/awp/base/cart.htm` I just need `abc.cn`.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897956/401092

Comment: You can also try `NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:{YOUR_URL_STRING_HERE}]; NSString *hostname = [url host];`

Comment: Wait, you want `h5.m.abc.com.cn` to give you `abc.com`? You need to clarify exactly what behavior you are looking for. This isn't a simple second-level domain parsing.

Comment: @BenZotto You are right, my bad. I made a stupid mistake. it should be `abc.com.cn` thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not the best way, but will work.

```
  NSString *host = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://h5.m.abc.com/awp/base/cart.htm?#!/awp/base/cart.htm"] host];

  NSArray  *parts = [host componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

  NSString *justDomain = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",
                      parts[parts.count - 2], parts[parts.count - 1]];

  NSLog(@"just domain %@", justDomain);
```

Comment: Or `NSString *justDomain = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", parts[parts.count - 2], parts[parts.count - 1]];`.